# How to check application come to fore ground in an UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

My application has integrated remote push notification service. Its working fine. I want to update the user unread notification count inside my app. If the notification received when the app is in background, and if user launched the app without clicking the notification instead of clicking the notification, user open the app using tapping the app icon (app has not closed just running in the background). So because of user still havent read the notification my viewcontroller should update the new notification count.

How can I do this? Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` in your ViewController's `viewWillAppear:` method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(updateGUI) 
                                      name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification 
                                      object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

And then update your UI with latest server data:

```
- (void)updateGUI {
    // Get latest unread request count from server and update UI
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove self as an observer in the `dealloc`.

Comment: Yes that a major point. Else you may end up in crash. Thanks @rckoenes

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me how to access the badge number in updateGUI method?

Comment: Although you could use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber` but as I mentioned in my post I would advise you to fetch it from server. Since your app is now coming to foreground you have the opportunity to get the latest count from your server directly. That will be latest and greatest value. Show loading overlay until response comes back.

Comment: No problem. Glad, it helped!